# Unique vector objects by specified object property

Tags: c++, vector, unique

What is the most effective way to obtain a vector having a unique specified object property (not unique objects just objects with unique specified property).

If y needed to be a unique property

```
point.x = 2 point.y = 3
point.x = 3 point.y = 3
point.x = 4 point.y = 4
point.x = 4 point.y = 5
```

Could become:

```
point.x = 3 point.y = 3
point.x = 4 point.y = 4
point.x = 4 point.y = 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is like this:

```
struct Point
{
    Point(int x_in,int y_in): x(x_in), y(y_in){}
    int x;
    int y;
};


int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    using namespace std;

    vector<Point> v;
    v.push_back(Point(2,3));
    v.push_back(Point(3,3));
    v.push_back(Point(4,4));
    v.push_back(Point(4,5));

    //First sort the vector as std::unique requires a sorted range
    stable_sort(v.begin(), v.end(), bind(&Point::y, _1) < bind(&Point::y, _2));

    //Make the elements in the vector unique and erase the duplicate elements from the vector
    v.erase(unique(v.begin(),v.end(), bind(&Point::y, _1) == bind(&Point::y, _2)), v.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to maintain the order of the elements you should insert your elements into a `set` or `hash_set` (depends on the number of elements) and create comparison and/or hash functions to tell the `(hash_)set` that objects with equal .y-property are "equal".

Comment: You probably want unordered_set rather than hash_set, since the former is more standardized.